# Adding a bit column in stored procedure select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that returns a row and an additional Bit column that says if that item is being used in other tables.

Principal Table: PrincipalId, RowA, RowB

TableA: TableAId, PrincipalId, NameA

TableB: TableBId, PrincipalId, NameB

TableC: TableCId, PrincipalId, NameC

How can I compare the PrincipalId to know if it is being used and add that result in the final select?

Thanks for your help.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_available
@principalId int
AS
BEGIN

    declare @available int
    set @available = 1
    IF EXISTS(select distinct PrincipalId from TableA where PrincipalId = @principalId
    and select distinct PrincipalId from TableB where PrincipalId = @principalId
    and select distinct PrincipalId from TableB where PrincipalId = @principalId)
        BEGIN
            set @available = 0
        END

    select RowA, RowB, @available as 'Available'
    from Principal
    where PrincipalId = @principalId
END
GO

exec sp_available 2
```

Comment: Don't use `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures. That is reserved for Microsoft and they have different name resolution rules compared to procedures that are not name thus. SQL Server does not have Boolean type, but `bit` is used as such when communicating to outside systems.

Comment: Agreed on `sp_` - [evidence here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Comment: `And` requires it to be used in all three tables. Not sure whether you're looking for all three or just one.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type.  (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.)  There is a [boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Comment: @HABO If you want to call something that you can't treat as data a "data type" be my guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your stored procedure to return an output parameter of `bit` type. The new definition would be as below. The default value of `@available` output parameter is 0 i.e. false. Also, as mentioned in comments, you can change the procedure name suitably to avoid the prefix of `sp`, though I have maintained the original name. You could prefix the name with your application acronym instead of sp.

Also, I have returned the bit column in an output parameter, but you could return it as part of row, if that's what you want. *If you choose to return it as part of SELECT row then the output parameter can be removed from the procedure definition.*

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_available
@principalId int,
@available bit = 0 OUTPUT --returns true i.e. 1 if PrincipalID is in all tables else 0 i.e.false
AS
BEGIN

    --start pessimistically by setting it to false
    set @available = 0

    IF EXISTS(select distinct PrincipalId from TableA where PrincipalId = @principalId)  
      AND EXISTS( select distinct PrincipalId from TableB where PrincipalId = @principalId)
      AND EXISTS (select distinct PrincipalId from TableB where PrincipalId = @principalId)
        BEGIN
            set @available = 1
        END

    select RowA, RowB, @available as 'Available'
    from Principal
    where PrincipalId = @principalId
END
GO

declare @avail bit
exec sp_available 2, @avail output
--you can use the value of @avail after above call
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `View` instead

```
CREATE VIEW viw_Principal AS
select 
    RowA, RowB, 
    CAST(CASE 
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE PrincipalId = Principal.PrincipalId) THEN 1
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE PrincipalId = Principal.PrincipalId) THEN 1
        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TableC WHERE PrincipalId = Principal.PrincipalId) THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS bit) as 'Available'
from Principal
```